# File/Scanner simple parsing issues

Tags: java, regex, string, file, java.util.scanner

Given a File and a Scanner object,

```
File simpleFile = ranFi.getSelectedFile();
Scanner text = new Scanner(simpleFile);
```

and these two commonplace statements:

```
    while(text.hasNext())
    {
        String currentLine = text.nextLine();
```

I'm trying to use Scanner/String class logical statements in a single if-statement clause which reads first line of file under a given matching regular expressions, such as:

```
String fp100 = "[S][:][A-Ze0-1]";
String fp200 = "[S][:][A-Z0-1][A-Z0-1]";
//other regexes…
```

and then invoke the appropriate Scanner/String class methods in same if-statement clause to read to second and onward/acceptable lines. I've read javadoc up and down but haven't figured out yet. Using currentLine.matches(regex) and text.nextLine().matches(regex), this code compiled,

```
    if(currentLine.matches(fp100)||currentLine.matches(fp200)||
       currentLine.matches(fp300) && text.nextLine().matches(fp100)||
       text.nextLine().matches(fp101) || text.nextLine().matches(fp200)||
       text.nextLine().matches(fp201) || text.nextLine().matches(fp300)||
       text.nextLine().matches(fp301))
    {
```

but throws an No Such Element Exception immediately. What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you in advance for your time. **EDIT:** I've included the stack trace, but removed the source code since this is project related.

[image: stack trace]

Comment: First of all `if` is not a loop, its a construct.. And what is this : - `NSEE`? Can you extend it in normal form?

Comment: No Such Element Exception error. I'll correct that statement though. thanks.

Comment: And you need to post the stack trace and some more code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. When you perform the `if` condition,  `text.nextLine()` may not be available.
2. if you mean to say, execute the if when any of the currentLine Matches + any of the nextLine match as true then wrap `||` arguments in a brace as:

   ```
   if((currentLine.matches(fp100)||currentLine.matches(fp200)||
      currentLine.matches(fp300)) && 
      (text.nextLine().matches(fp100)||
       text.nextLine().matches(fp101) || text.nextLine().matches(fp200)||
       text.nextLine().matches(fp201) || text.nextLine().matches(fp300)||
       text.nextLine().matches(fp301)))
   ```

I think you wanted to write your `while` loop something like this:

```
        while(text.hasNextLine()){
           String currentLine = text.nextLine();
           String nextLine = "";
           if(text.hasNextLine())[
               nextLine  = text.nextLine();
           }

           /**ACC conditions*/
           if((currentLine.matches(fp100)||currentLine.matches(fp200)
                || currentLine.matches(fp300)) 
                && (nextLine.matches(fp100)|| nextLine.matches(fp101) 
                     || nextLine.matches(fp200)
                     || nextLine.matches(fp201) || nextLine.matches(fp300)
                     || nextLine.matches(fp301)) {
                                //current line is OK
                                System.out.println(currentLine);
                                output.write(currentLine);
                                output.write("\n");
                                abc1List.add(currentLine);
                                lineOK++;               

                                //next line is OK
                                System.out.println(nextLine);
                                output.write(nextLine);
                                output.write("\n");
                                abc1List.add(nextLine);
                                // <-- not sure if you want OK as 1 or 2 here 
                                lineOK++;           
           } /**REJ conditions*/
           else if(!currentLine.matches(fp100)||!currentLine.matches(fp101)||
                  !currentLine.matches(fp200)||!currentLine.matches(fp201)||
                  !currentLine.matches(fp300)||!currentLine.matches(fp301)){   
                        System.out.println("invalid cfg; terminating....");
                   System.exit(0);
           }
       }//end of while
```

Comment: @ Yogendra I'm going to have to go through line by line since I'm unsure of what the issue is why it keep terminating even if valid (e.g. counter,...)and inspect more thoroughly but thanks you very much for your advice

Comment: @madrush Thanks. Please let me know, if you need further help.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop should start with `while(text.hasNextLine())` if you are using `text.nextLine().matches(regex)` inside the loop. Be careful. If `text.hasNext()` evaluates to true, it doesn't mean that `text.nextLine()` will be non-null.

Comment: saw that too. First you check if a nextLine exists, and if so use it. Then you just try to use the following line without checking for its existence. After reading the last line you also try to read the following line, which does not exist, and thats why you get a NoSuchElementException.

Comment: @ Vincenzo, jlordo - alright I'm figuring it out thanks guys!